Vscodium scans all files of the git repository where I am in and takes 100% cpu time during that period
Vscodium scans all files of the git repository where I am in and takes 100% cpu time during that period. This also happens when I start vscodium with 'codium --disable-extensions'.
I checked this behaviour with Versions 1.79 and 1.93 where it happened.
Because I have a relatively big git repo this process takes a lot of time and wastes cpu cycles at every vscodium startup.
I don't trust this behaviour. What is it good for and can I switch it off?
Thanks in advance,
Frank Schwidom

In the meantime I found a solution. There is an entry in the settings: "Files: Watcher Exclude" when I add the pattern '**' then it is silent.
